# ReportViewer datos remotos

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, reportviewer, ssrs

Buen día.

Tengo un problema con los reportes (.RDLC) de mi proyecto (ASP.Net MVC), resulta que lo acabo de subir a Azure (App Service).

Yo estaba trabajando con una base de datos local, la cual no tenía credenciales (usuario, password), con la autenticación de Windows.

Ahora estoy utilizando una base de datos remota, los informes (.RDLC) no funcionan, con la aplicación que uso para diseñar los informes, actualice el datasource, pero supongo que no se esta guardando las credenciales, esta es la cadena de conexión.

```
<ConnectionProperties>
  <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
  <ConnectString>Data Source=miservidor;Initial Catalog=DataBase</ConnectString>
</ConnectionProperties>
```

En la vista preliminar que me da la aplicación de diseño (ya actualizado con la bd remota), si me funciona, pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación, no sale ningún dato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá está la solución:

```
<ConnectionProperties> 
    <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider> 
    <ConnectString>Data Source=mvc.syncfusion.com;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;User ID=ssrs1;Password=RDLReport1</ConnectString> 
</ConnectionProperties>
```